# find username,databasename and version in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

while using database under MySQL how can i determine my current MySQL version,database name I'm working and logged in username ?

is it possible to get through using query ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this.

```
mysql> select version(),user(),database();
+-----------+----------------+------------+
| version() | user()         | database() |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
| 5.1.41    | root@localhost | bank       |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DATABASE(), USER(), VERSION();
```

See ["Information Functions" in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html) for more details